# JAVA - how do I save user inputs into array with a method that has no parameters?

Tags: java, arrays

i have been racking my mind over this for 2 days and i still do not know how to get it to work.

Basically this is a game where multiple players can play, it has a menu, and also shows highscores.

After the person presses option 1, it should load makeGuess(); and then be able to input his guess to get a score. But i am unable to save these inputs into an array. How else can i do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;
public class game
{   
 public static void main(String [] args){
   System.out.print("Number of players? ");
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numplayers = kb.nextInt();
   String [] playersArray = new String[numplayers];
   int guessesArray[] = new int [numplayers];
   int currscoresArray[] = new int [numplayers];
   int addscoresArray[] = new int [numplayers];
   int finalscoresArray [] = new int [numplayers];
   populateArray(playersArray);
   makeGuess(guessesArray);
}

public static void populateArray( String[] x){
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i<x.length ; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Player "+(i+1)+": ");
        x[i]=kb.nextLine();  
   }
}

public static void displayMenu(){
    int choice=0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] args = {};
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. Make Guess");
        System.out.println("2. List Winner");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        choice = kb.nextInt();
        if (choice==0){
            System.out.print("Do you want to play a new game? Y/N: ");
            String ans = kb.next();
            if (ans.equals ("Y") || ans.equals ("y")){
                main(args);
            }
            break;
        } 
        switch (choice){
            case 1: makeGuess(); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Option 2 selected"); break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
     System.out.println("End of program");System.exit(0);
}

public static void makeGuess(){   
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int secret = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    int guess = kb.nextInt();
    int diff = (int)(Math.abs(guess - secret));
    int score=0; 
    for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
       System.out.print("Enter your guess player "+(i+1)+": ");
       x[i]=kb.nextInt();
    } 
    if (diff == 0){
        score=score+10;
    }else if(diff<=10){
        score=score+5;
    }else if(diff<=20){
        score=score+2;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        x[i]=score;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your array **in the class**, and make it `static`;

```
static int[] guessesArray;
```

Then, in you main method, initialize it.

And from you `makeGuess()` method, I can guess that you need to store it in an array `x`. Just change it to array `guessesArray`.

Comment: hi thank you for the answer, its exactly what i wanted.

However now i have another issue. If i can save the values now in an array, how do I then output the values in a table form like "Name          Guess    Score" because even if i use a for loop i can only loop 1 array but i cannot put another array with integers beside it?

Comment: @ShaoQi If all the arrays have the same size, then with one control variable you can get values of all the arrays.However, I will only be able to give you the correct answer if I know exactly how you want the output.

Comment: I've got it figured out! Thanks so much for replying.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this problem is to make your variables from main fields of your class and make the necessary changes to your program that come with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could the method so that it takes an array as a parameter:

```
public static void makeGuess(int[] x){   
    //Your current code
}
```

If you really don't want the method to have any parameters, you need to move the declaration of your `guessesArray` outside the main method, then initialize it inside the main method before you call your method:

```
public class game {
    static int[] guessesArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Number of players? ");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numplayers = kb.nextInt();
        String [] playersArray = new String[numplayers];

        //Initialize it here
        guessesArray = new int [numplayers];

        //Rest of your code

        //Call your function with no parameter
        makeGuess();
    }
}
```